# Understanding an LP where every feasible solution is optimal

Tags: linear-programming

I'm trying to study for a linear programming exam and I came across this statement:

"For a linear program in standard form with coefficient matrix *A*, if the cost vector *c* belongs to the row space of *A* then every feasible solution is optimal."

I understand kind of intuitively that it's true but thoroughly. Can anyone offer a more formal proof of why? Or at least help me wrap my head around it more concretely.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is $m \times n$ and your LP is to minimize $cx$ subject to $Ax=b$.  You are given that there exists $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $y A = c$.  Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an arbitrary feasible solution.  Then $$cx = (yA)x = yAx = y(Ax) = yb,$$
which does not depend on $x$.  That is, every feasible solution has the same objective value $yb$.